# tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.selinux'

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am installing Openshift Origin All-in-One Server using below links

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#downloading-the-binary

after download when i did

```
tar -xf openshift-origin-server-v3.10.0-rc.0-c20e215-linux-64bit.tar.gz -C /opt/redhat
```

It throws following output but directory got untar n desired directory

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just encountered the same.

Based on http://lifeonubuntu.com/tar-errors-ignoring-unknown-extended-header-keyword/

"It turns out this is just an issue with tar files created on Mac OS X. Mac OS X uses BSD tar and creates some extra info that is not recognized by GNU tar."

It should extract just fine, so no need to worry about it.

NOTE: The following is bad advice unless you perform other checks to make sure the file is fine. This will hide legitimate errors encountered while trying to extract.

If you'd prefer to not see those error lines you could just redirect the errors to `/dev/null` like this:

```
tar -xf openshift-origin-server-v3.10.0-rc.0-c20e215-linux-64bit.tar.gz -C /opt/redhat 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: This is bad advice. This would redirect *all* errors to `/dev/null` and thus hide legitimate other possible warning messages.

Comment: True that... didn't think of that at the time. I guess if you do other checks like sha to make sure the file isn't damaged you might still be "safe enough".

Comment: I am getting this error is being thrown up by the tar in WSL2 Debian when working with the tar created by `wsl --export <WSL Image Name> <Export file>`.

Comment: instead of 2> /dev/null one could 2> >(grep -v "Ignoring unknown extended header" >&2)

Answer (score 25):

use `--no-xattrs` when you create a archive file using BSD `tar` in macOS, which will turn off `xattr` headers in the generated archive file.

```
tar -cz --no-xattrs --exclude .* -f zippath source
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer works

Comment: The `--exclude .*` part made computer act really weird and produce a beeping noise (M2 Mac). It should probably be `--exclude=".*"` instead or something along the lines, yet it only removed the `.DS_Store` files and kept the `._FILE:OR_DIRECTORY_NAME` ones.

Comment: Sorry, but the `--no-xattrs` part nowadays seems a bit redundant, as this is the default setting... (see [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Extended-File-Attributes.html))

Answer (score 10):

If you understand why the warning is happening and you want to suppress it, use, `--warning=no-unknown-keyword`

Comment: This flag is supported only by GNU `tar`, so I had to do `tar xf yourFile.tar.gz --warning=no-unknown-keyword || tar xf yourFile.tar.gz` in order to support both MacOS and Linux.

Comment: thanks! other useful flags: `tar --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions --warning=no-unknown-keyword --warning=no-timestamp --delay-directory-restore`

Answer (score 1):

Addition to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53190789/17602274) by [aiguofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815486/aiguofer), if you don't want to see these errors, but also don't want to suppress all errors, you can just filter it out with the following:

```
tar -xf openshift-origin-server-v3.10.0-rc.0-c20e215-linux-64bit.tar.gz -C /opt/redhat 2>&1 | grep -v 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security.selinux'
```

Or if to suppress all xattr.security related errors:

```
tar -xf openshift-origin-server-v3.10.0-rc.0-c20e215-linux-64bit.tar.gz -C /opt/redhat 2>&1 | grep -v 'LIBARCHIVE.xattr.security'
```